# Two fonts in row of cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want two fonts in the same cell. The second row, is price and the unit of measure (for example ea, dz, cs, pk).

When I work on one cell, the `activeCell.character` is looking for a start for the first font and a start for the second font.
Due to the price changing is size from 3 numbers including those after the decimal place to 4, 5 and 6 this method won't work.

I need something that will have the cell as one font and then 3 places to the right of the decimal place "." change the font.

[image]

```vb
Sub TwoFonts2()

    Dim MyPos, SearchChar
    SearchChar = "."

    Rows("2:2").Select
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=8).Font
        .Name = "ITC Avant Garde Std Bk"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 26
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With

    With MyPos = (InStr(SearchChar, x, " ") + 3)
        .Name = "ITC Avant Garde Std Bk"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 14
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Instr` to locate the point, then add 3.

Comment: @Rory  Ok, started to change code to use Instr but still doesn't work to what I need

Comment: I thought you wanted to look for the decimal point, not a space?

Comment: @Rory I am which is why SearchChar is set to "."

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way. It accepts spaces before the number, which is mandatory to have a dot as decimal separator. The string after the last space (for the second font) may have any number of characters. If only one space, before the last small font characters, the code can be simplified, directly returning the space position:

```
Sub SplitCharactersFonts()
   Dim x As String, secF As Long
   x = ActiveCell.Value
  
   secF = InStr(InStr(x, "."), x, " ") + 1 'find space starting from dot position
   With ActiveCell.Characters(1, secF - 1).Font
        .size = 26
        'do watever you need with the first part
   End With
   With ActiveCell.Characters(secF, Len(x)).Font
        .size = 14
         'do whatever you need with the second part
   End With
End Sub
```